# Confusing trashes, can't delete stuff

Tags: linux, usb-storage, opensuse, trash

I'm "cleaning" my computer and USB keys and this requires a whole lot of deleting. I've gone though everything on my OS HDD, and now moving on to keys. My trash is initially EMPTY.

When trying to delete something from my key, I get this error:

> The trash has reached its maximum size! 
>   Cleanup the trash manually.

My trash is EMPTY. So I look at the `.Trash-1000` file on the key itself. I try deleting that and get:

> Could not rename file /media/N00B/.Trash-1000.

So now I'm sad my computer is playing tricks on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trash, or recycle bin, is one of the worst inventions of mankind. The way linux desktops handle the trash on usb keys is aggravating.

On most file managers you can delete bypassing the trash using the key combination <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>. You should be able to delete the trash directory this way.

You can also try to delete the trash directory from a terminal using the following command:

```
rm -rf /media/N00B/.Trash-1000
```